# Access Global variables in resource files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, embedded-resource

I have an MVC project where I have a Global function which returns url's. Here is one of them:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Account.Models
{
    public class ApplicationStrings
    {

        public static string ApplicationString(){

            return "http://localhost11234/Studentbook";

    }

    }

}
```

I have resource files where I store email body for different emails that go out. This is an Embedded Resource.

How can I access URL's from my global function in my resource files?

I try the following way but dont see the links:

```
<html>
<body> 
<br> Student ID :  <a href= ApplicationStrings.ApplicationString() + ?id=JD1123>JD1123</a><br>       
</body>
</html>
```

I see the following:

```
Student ID : JD1123
```

Here JD1123 is a link, The link takes me to **"ApplicationStrings.ApplicationString()"** instead of **"http://localhost11234/Studentbook?id=JD1123"**

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you are trying to do, at least not directly.  The resource strings are static items that do not get changed automatically when you access them.  So basically, you are getting back out precisely what you put in.  The computer is not smart enough to know that it should make a method call to get your configuration string stuck in there.

Instead, you will need to write a piece of intermediate code that searches your resource string for specific items to replace (perhaps flag them with <% %> or something), then use Regex.Replace to insert the correct text.  This is fairly trivial to accomplish.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/string/regex/article.php/c2791/Using-Regular-Expressions-for-SearchReplace.htm